# UK Contract - Notice in lieu pay

Tags: united-kingdom, contractors

I had a Limited company UK contract, with Agency & worked at their end-client.

After working for few months .
It was suddenly terminated by the hiring manager (i.e. the end client,, no reason given in writing).
But she told (in writing ) that - they will be paying for the notice.

But in later email, hiring manager told that (possibly trying to save money as I have left)- they have only 2 week's notice on contract (whereas in my contract its full 1 month notice)

I recall that - just before joining, they  increased the Notice period duration & made me to sign it, on last minute.

Furthermore, no amount was paid, after I left, (not even for the 2 weeks). 
Agency will be now more concerned about their relation with client than asking for my money.

What to do?
Shall I send a invoice to Agency for full 1-month asking for the money (& attaching the email from Hiring manager, which was already forwarded to them on day of getting Fired)

Thanking in advance
Cheers

Comment: Send them the bill for the full one month - stated in the contract - if they got that wrong it's their problem. Also check out the small claims court and think about going that route - works well - a friend did that...

Comment: The agency's relationship & contract with the end-client is not your problem or concern. It's your relationship and contract with the agency which are relevant here. This is the contract you should be holding the agency to - and it's not your problem if the agency chooses not to pursue the end-client for reimbursement.

Comment: Voting to close question that seeks advice on [company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change/2694#2694)

Answer (score 4):

Their relationship is not your concern at all. The reality is that you have a contract that you signed for and they have broken such contract.

Send the invoice to the agency and advise them you expect prompt payment. Make them aware that failure to pay will result in additional costs as you would need to proceed with this case to the small claims court.

Continue your search and probably use a different agency from now on...

EDIT: suggested in comments:

nd don't forget to add interest and compensation, at 8% above base rate and between £40 and £100 respectively (Search: Late Payment of Commercial Debts (Interest) Act 1998). I would also add £50 for every letter/email you have to write.

I would recommend this if you go via the small claims court. If you are just interested in your money, just try and be amicable in the first instance.

Comment: +1 and don't forget to add interest and compensation, at 8% above base rate and between £40 and £100 respectively (Search: Late Payment of Commercial Debts (Interest) Act 1998). I would also add £50 for every letter/email you have to write.

Comment: @Justin if taking it to small claims court, definitely! I will add that...

Comment: I am bit concerned that- end client being also manipulative, could change their stand & say we just terminated the contract. Recall she was trying to reduce paying from 1 month to only 2 weeks.